# Scala libraries incompatibility

Tags: scala, scala-ide

```
akka-actor_2.13-2.5.23.jar of play-scala-seed build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.13.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.
```

I have many errors of this type in my scala project. How do I resolve such errors?

I am using Scala IDE.

**build.sbt:**

```
name := """play-scala-seed"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "4.0.3" % Test

// Adds additional packages into Twirl
//TwirlKeys.templateImports += "com.example.controllers._"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
// play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport += "com.example.binders._"
```

I guess I need to change `Scala installation` to 2.13, right? ( I am referring to the `Scala installation` option that shows up in the project properties after right clicking on the project in the IDE )

But, the only options available in the dropdown are 2.10,2.11 and 2.12. How do I add 2.13 into my IDE?

The solutions in similar questions did not work for me.

Comment: Try updating your IDE. It should show Scala 2.13 as an option to use. If not, consider IntelliJ (which has been updated with support for 2.13).

Comment: I just updated it, so I think it may be another issue

Comment: Please consider using IntelliJ IDEA or Visual Studio Code, because Scala IDE is not mantained anymore.

Comment: http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html, you are right, the scala IDE website does not mention 2.13 anywhere, I had no idea it was no longer being maintained

Comment: can you show us your plugins.sbt file as well?